# How to display error including content of cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I want to display each element of a cell array in new line as part of an error message in Matlab.

```
classdef MyEnum < int32
    enumeration
         red (1) 
         blue (2) 
    end
end    

[m, s] = enumeration('MyEnum');
error('Expected one of the values below: %s', s);
```

That code didn't work and returned following error: "Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs."

I want display an error message like this.

```
 Expected one of the values below:
 'red'
 'blue'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If the cells only contain character vectors

You can expand the cell into a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of individual inputs to [`error`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html), and dynamically build the format specifier by repeating `'%s\n'` the appropriate number of times. This encloses each string in single quotes.

```
s = {'aaa', 'bbbb'};
error(['Expected one of the values below:\n' repmat('''%s''\n', 1, numel(s))], s{:})
```

gives the error message

```
Expected one of the values below:
'aaa'
'bbbb'
```

### If the cells can contain character vectors or numeric matrices

In this case, instead of enclosing in single quotes you can apply [`mat2str`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) to each cell's contents:

```
s = {'aaa', [1 2 3; 4 5 6]};
t = cellfun(@mat2str, s, 'UniformOutput', false);
error(['Expected one of the values below:\n' repmat('%s\n', 1, numel(t))], t{:})
```

gives

```
Expected one of the values below:
'aaa'
[1 2 3;4 5 6]
```

Comment: Yes, partly solves my problem. But, how can I add single quote around each element?